# C# Ternary Operator used in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use the **ternary operator** to reflect this logic?

```
if (a = 1)
{
    somevalue = "hello";
} 
else if (a = 2)
{
    someValue = "world";
}
else if (a = 3)
{
    someValue = "hellWorld";
}
```

I am doing the following in a LINQ Query:

```
using (var data = new DAL())
{
    var result = data.Holidays.AsNoTracking()
                 .Where(x => x.RequesterId == userId)
                 .Select(x => new HolidayModel
                 {
                     HolidayId = x.HolidayId,
                     FromDate = x.FromDate,
                     ToDate = x.ToDate,
                     AuthorisationStatus = x.InternalHolidayStatus == 1 ?
                         HolidayAuthStatus.Pending :
                         HolidayAuthStatus.Rejected,
                     DateModified = x.ModifiedDate
                 }).ToList();

    return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

`HolidayAuthStatus` is an enum, which has three values in it (`Pending` (1), `Authorised` (2) and `Rejected` (3)); and I would like to reflect this in code when assigning the value of `AuthorisationStatus`.

Comment: Clearly you are using it already so what's the problem? Also if `HolidayAuthStatus` corresponds to `AuthorisationStatus` you can just do a straight cast.

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-Objects, LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change to this

```
AuthorisationStatus = (HolidayAuthStatus)x.InternalHolidayStatus
```

if integer values for your HolidayAuthStatus match InternalHolidayStatus values it will work. Ternary operator here will look horible. If your status code doesn't match it's better to make function accepting `int status` and returning `HolidayAuthStatus`

```
HolidayAuthStatus GetStatus(int status)
{
    if(status == 1) return HolidayAuthStatus.Pending;
    if(status == 2) return HolidayAuthStatus.Authorised;
    if(status == 3) return HolidayAuthStatus.Rejected;
    return HolidayAuthStatus.Unknown; // for e.g.
}
```

and use it like:

```
AuthorisationStatus = GetStatus(x.InternalHolidayStatus)
```

EDIT:

as @James said method will work only in Linq-to-object not in Linq-to-entities

Comment: The method approach will most likely only work with LINQ To Objects.

Comment: @James good point I haven't seen `DAL()` in using, I'll write it in my answer, thanks

Comment: @wudzik thanks, this is neat way but it doesnt work within a LINQ query. This error was returned: 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Timeshet.Web.Models.Enum.HolidayAuthStatus GetStatus(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @t_plusplus yeah I know now, because it's linq-to-entities I missed that and James pointed it. First approach will work with linq-to-entites, second only in linq-to-objects. Check first answer with `(HolidayAuthStatus)x.InternalHolidayStatus`

Comment: @t_plusplus you can still make the method way work, however, you need to materialize the query and *then* do your projection i.e. `data.Holidays.AsNoTracking().Where(...).AsEnumerable().Select(...).ToList();`

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. I think it's hard to get the operator precedence right with the ternary operator, so I prefer using parantheses:

```
AuthorizationStatus = x.InternalHolidayStatus == 1 ?
    HolidayStatus.Pending :
    (x.InternalHolidayStatus == 2 ?
        HolidayStatus.Rejected : 
        (x.InternalHolidayStatus == 3 ?
            HolidayStatus.Authorized : 
            HolidayStatus.Invalid))
```

Since this is a mapping to an enum it's also a possibility to use a cast as @wodzik suggests, if it is possible and feasible to use the same values for the enum values as they are in the database.

To use that you will have to explictility assign values to the enums

```
public enum HolidayStatus
{
    Pending = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
    Authorized = 3
}
```

Then you can do:

```
AuthorizeStatus = (HolidayStatus)x.InternalHolidayStatus
```

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for formatting? Unfortunately there is a no switch-case operator in C#, only statements which cannot be used in LINQ queries.

Comment: I would not nest ternary operators.

Comment: @RichardEv what's wrong with nesting ternary operators? You lose some readability but it's still *functionally* correct.

Comment: The question was specifically asking if it is possible to use the ternary operator and that's my answer. I know the code is ugly, but for Linq-to-Entities it is not possible to break out the expression to a separate method.

Comment: For me (and recent teams I've worked with) it's all about the readability. But you're correct that ternary was what was asked for...and I know there are limitations when using Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: I just made a formatting change - see what you think. Whilst doing that I think I also found a bug in the condition of the third ternary operator.