# Use if statement in Action C#

Tags: c#

I have a bool variable `_settings.Value.UsePostgreSQL` and method 
`AddConfiguration(this IServiceCollection builder, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> dbContextOptionsAction = null)`
Is it possible to use `if` condition in method with `Action` as a parameter? Something like this:

```
_settings.Value.UsePostgreSQL = true;
var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
services.AddConfiguration(builder =>
    _settings.Value.UsePostgreSQL ?
        builder.UseSqlServer(_settings.Value.ConnectionString, options =>
            options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)) :
        builder.UseNpgsql(_settings.Value.ConnectionString, options =>
            options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
```

While I'm trying to implement this I have an error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: I dont even see an if statement

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or a practical one. Please post the code that gives you an error? Of course, you can use the tertiary operator `(x) => condition(x) ? expr_A : expr_B` in a delegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Ternary Operator used in LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977327/c-sharp-ternary-operator-used-in-linq-query)

Comment: @maccettura sorry, I'm using conditional operator instead of `if` statement, but problem is the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25924102/125981 might also help you here

Comment: You can use ternary operator in lambda only for returning value.

Comment: "Put on hold as not clear what you're asking". Seriously?

Comment: @EdPlunkett There seems to be an influx of erroneously closed questions.  You would think users would read into a question a bit before just voting to close `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @EdPlunkett look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969344/unable-to-remove-a-special-character-from-string) from yesterday.  I am still raging about it.  5 people voted to reopen and one guy came back in and closed it again

Comment: @maccettura I suspect a groupthink effect. I've seen a few closed as a duplicate of something only tangentially related, like somebody voted carelessly, and then four others saw "close(1)" and said "me too, let God sort 'em out!" without even reading. People (I think we've both noticed some of the same ones) get jaded and trigger happy I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C#, this is an expression, not a statement. As a complete statement, it won't compile. It would be fine in Perl, [JavaScript](https://jsfiddle.net/61ervsvw/), and probably other languages, but syntax is arbitraryish so you can't reliably generalize from one language to another.

```
a ? b : c;
```

It isn't an "if statement"; it's a [conditional expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). This is your code with an if statement; I expect that this version will compile for you, but let me know.

```
services.AddConfiguration(builder =>
{
    if (_settings.Value.UsePostgreSQL) {
        builder.UseSqlServer(_settings.Value.ConnectionString, 
            options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    } else {
        builder.UseNpgsql(_settings.Value.ConnectionString, 
            options => options.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    }
});
```

It looks like `services.AddConfiguration()` expects an `Action<T>`, not a `Func<T>`, so the compiler will require the body of the lambda to be a statement, not an expression.

This is a statement *containing* a conditional expression, and it will compile:

```
var d = a ? b : c;
```

That's what the conditional operator is for, but it's not what you were trying to do.